# implication of $\sigma$-finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For $(X, M, \mu)$, if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then does it imply that $\exists E_1 \subset E_2 \subset \cdots \text{ with } \cup_i E_i = X$ and $\mu(E_i) < \infty$?

In my opinion, the statement isn't right. It's equivalent to saying it's finite measure? Since with this statement, by continuity from below, $\mu(X) = \mu(\cup_i E_i) = \lim_i \mu(E_i) < \infty$

This is actually part of one solution given by our prof. similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1396700/399379) for the problem but instead of assuming $E_i$ being partitions.

Comment: Take $F_i=E_1\cup E_2\cup\cdots \cup E_i$, given the collection $\{E_n\}$ of sets of finie measure whose union is $X$. Your limit need not be finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does imply this. For example just take $\mathbb R$ with Lebesgue measure, and set $E_n=(-n,n)$. Your error is in stating that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(E_n)<\infty$, as that is clearly not the case. If each $\mu(E_n)$ is larger than the last why do you think the limit must be finite? This is just a sequence of real numbers. You don't think that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2<\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider on $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure the sets $E_i=[-i,i]$.

The crux is that each individual set $E_i$ having finite measure does not mean that the limit of the measures is finite. This has little to do with measure theory, it's about real-valued sequences and their limits.